# Outlook 2010 Reply event example in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010

Reply Event is already available in form Visual Basic. But I required in the form of C#.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `event ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler Reply`? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.reply.aspx)